# Capistrano stage values do not override defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I define some stage specific capistrano variables but they do not override default values.

config/deploy/staging.rb:

```
set :user, 'ec2-user'
set :rails_env, 'staging'

set :domain,      'test.etask.me'
```

config/deploy.rb:

```
set :application, 'etask'

set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
set :user, 'ec2-user'

set(:unicorn_env) { rails_env }

role(:web) { domain }
role(:app) { domain }
role(:db, :primary => true) { domain }

set(:deploy_to)    { "/home/#{user}/#{application}/#{fetch :rails_env}" }
set(:current_path) { File.join(deploy_to, current_dir) }

default_run_options[:pty] = false

require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :using_rvm, true
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'
set :rvm_type, :user

set :repository,  'git@bitbucket.org:adaptiveservices/etask-website.git'
set :scm,         :git
set :branch,      'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :keep_releases, 3

set :use_sudo,    false
set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache

set :git_enable_submodules, 1
```

cap deploy output:

```
triggering load callbacks
  * 2013-10-15 15:44:25 executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2013-10-15 15:44:25 executing `multistage:ensure'
  * 2013-10-15 15:44:25 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-10-15 15:44:25 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-10-15 15:44:25 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:adaptiveservices/etask-website.git master"
    command finished in 2270ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/ec2-user/etask/production/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/ec2-user/etask/production/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q
 --hard 88e8556a3cce96e77d51a40b96f2dcd1437c939a && git submodule -q init && git submodule -q sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git
 submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master --depth 1 git@bitbucket.org:adaptiveservices/etask-website.git /home/ec2-user/etask/production/shared/cache
d-copy && cd /home/ec2-user/etask/production/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 88e8556a3cce96e77d51a40b96f2dcd1437c939a && git submodule -q init && git submodule -q sync && export GIT_RECURS
IVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE; fi"
```

As you can see capistrano thinks that it is production environment (look at the cd /home/ec2-user/etask/**production**/shared/cached-copy). It uses default values instead of defined in deploy/staging.rb. Even if I check what the value of user variable - it throws an error (value is not defined) in spite the fact that I set user inside deploy/staging.rb.

I have done all the things as described in [capistrano wiki](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn/wiki/Using-capistrano-unicorn-with-multistage-environment). I looked through tons of other related posts and they do not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I introduced a hack to make it work. I have replaced

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```

with

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :stage, ARGV.select { |arg| stages.include? arg }.first || 'staging'
load "config/deploy/#{stage}.rb"
```

It also takes three lines but it DOES work. I hope I will get rid of that code when migrating to capistrano 3.x

Comment: I love you.. it works.

Answer (score 0):

move this `require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'`  to the bottom of deploy.rb:

and run
`cap staging deploy`(not `cap deploy staging`)
Try that way it will use overridden params from staging env.

Comment: `cap deploy` will result in `cap staging deploy` because staging is default stage. Anyway both approaches produce the same output that is shown above.

Comment: moved require to the bottom and checked both `deploy staging` and `staging deploy` - the same result :(

Comment: thats weird.
we use it differently:
deploy.rb (only contain these two lines):

    `set :stages, %w(staging production)`
    `require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'`

and then staging.rb and production.rb have all the stuff defined for the environment(some duplicate code though but that works)

Comment: I also have the same thing in two other projects. And it works there! But it does not work here. So weird. Can not fix that for the whole day